# dc.js and JQuerys document ready doesn't work

Tags: jquery, dc.js

i add some charts with dc.js on my webpage. For all my other stuff i used jQuery.ready with this code:

```
  <html>
  <head> 
  ....
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
   //Javascriptcode
  };
 </script>
 </head>
 </body>
  <div id="chart"></div>
  ....
 </body>
 </html>
```

I creat the chart and bind it to the div: *chart*. 
In this case, it dosent work. (cant see any chart)
When i change the position from the *div* to the *head*, it works..?
I already tryed:
     `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { js-code..});`

But i get the same problem. (No Error-message).
I use JQuery, because i creat some other charts with c3.js without any problems..

What is my mistake?

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link href="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src=" https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/crossfilter.js"></script>
    <script src="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/dc.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
const socket = io.connect('localhost:3000');

        var Flightnumbers = dc.rowChart("#chart1");
       
        socket.emit('Flightnumbers');

        $(document).ready(function () {
            // console.log("ready!");
            dc.config.defaultColors(d3.schemeSet1);
            socket.on('Flightnumbers-b', function (data) {
                console.log(data);
               
                var tmp = crossfilter(data);
               

                var FlightNumbersDim = tmp.dimension(function (d) {
                    return d["Target"];
                });              

                var FlightNumbersGroup = FlightNumbersDim.group();                           
                dc.renderAll();

            });
       });
  
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="chart1"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Try to move `dc.js` including at the end of the `<body />` tag. It probably scans the page when loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  but this dosent work.  :/

Comment: Could you create a working (well, non-working) snippet? You can use `Code Snippet` here in the question editor or any other third-party solutions.

Comment: Hi, i edit my first comment.

Comment: I've never seen the need for `$.ready` with dc.js - I just put the chart setup scripts after any relevant DOM elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this row

```
var Flightnumbers = dc.rowChart("#chart1");
```

You calling it before the element actually appears in the HTML.
So you should move this row to the `$(document).ready(function () {})` wrapper as well, then it will look for the element when the document will be built already.

Note, that `Flightnumbers` variable won't be accessible anymore globally. You can set it directly to the global namespace with `window.Flightnumbers =` if you need it for any reason. However, you should avoid using a global namespace, though it is an offtopic here.